# yii1 bootstrap for large screens > 1200

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

Application on yii1 with bootstrap
My application shows tables with many columns 
So for large screens I want to make sure that there is not too much space lost on the left and right
Bootstrap does not seem to manage screensize > 1200
I'm on 1920 x 1080 and so I get what you can see in joined picture
[image: large screen]
Is there a not too complicated way to manage large size ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap3 in you yii1 application for use all the width for large screen you can use

```
 .container-fluid
```

.

```
<div class='container-fluid'>

</div>
```

for the rest you can use the tipical grid system of boostrap

for boostrap 2  you could try using

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
  <div class = "row-fluid">
```

Comment: I'm bottstrap 2.0.3 - and this does not work in this version
Do you think I need to go to version3 or is there another solution ?

Comment: thanks - and sorry my test was not ok 
Cause you are right about container-fluid but this also affects the space above and so it seems that first 2 lines of any page are hidden beyond the navbar

Comment: @G.Trennert  .. probably you must add a container fluid also for the navbar  or the div that wrap navabar

Comment: No this does not change anything
I added 3 <br /> to make show the hidden lines which works even if this seems to be somehow not really perfect - any other solution I could try ?